# Is it possible to include a quotation mark as part of an nsstring from server?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, nsstring

I have a label that displays inches. I would like to display the number with the inch symbol (") or quotation mark. Can I do this with an nsstring? Thanks!

I know this works

NSString *someString = @"This is a quotation mark: \"";
NSLog(@"%@", someString );

but i am getting a data from server like this -
Video (anxiety): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii2FHbtVJzc&sns=em

so when i try to save this data in sql lite,update failed   beacuse of the  " in the server response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly include quotation marks in strings. As long as you use such strings properly, there should be no issues. You run into issues when you pass strings with quotes to methods that have special interpretation for them, such as methods that forward your strings to SQL parser. In these cases quotes need to be hidden, for example through the use of parameterized SQL statements.

However, it does not look like you are including a quotation mark in your string for a good purpose: displaying a measurement in inches is a display concern, there is absolutely no need to include the quotation mark in the server response or in the data written to the database. Instead, you should pass the measurement in its native form (an integer or a floating-point number), and add the quotation mark at the last moment, when you are about to display the string to users.

For example, you can do it like this:

```
int measurement = 42;
NSString *measurementDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\"", measurement];
```

Comment: This is definitely correct.  Just put \ in front of the quotation you want included in the string.